# A pop-up window that used to open through the console stopped opening

Tags: html, forms, popup, popupmenu

**Hi everyone**

I just started learning HTML so I barely understand what I'm doing, sorry in advance.

So basically, there used to be an option to delete your account from a website by going to the console and writing a specific line.

You used to simply type:
***profileModule.openDeletAccountModal();*** and a pop-up window would open that asks you to re-enter your password and that's it.

However, lately they changed something and after writing down that line nothing opens up and instead you get:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')***

***at Object.openDeletAccountModal (profile.js?v=1.34120.518:1:1001)***

Inside the .js you get some more lines:

```js
var profileModule=(function(){var _showRemoveProfileLink=function(){var urlParameterToShowRemoveProfile='removeprofile';var url_string=window.location.href;var url=new URL(url_string);var c=url.searchParams.get(urlParameterToShowRemoveProfile);if(c!==null){document.querySelector('#ask-delete-account').style.display='block';if(c==='open')openDeletAccountModal();}};var handleEvent=function(){_showRemoveProfileLink();var btnDeleteEl=document.querySelector('#btn-delete-account');document.querySelector('#delete-account-current-password').addEventListener('input',function(event){if(event.target.value.length>0){btnDeleteEl.classList.remove('disable-button');btnDeleteEl.removeAttribute('disabled');}else{btnDeleteEl.classList.add('disable-button');btnDeleteEl.setAttribute('disabled','');}});document.querySelector('.dark-nilon').addEventListener('click',function(event){profileModule.closeDeletAccountModal();});};var openDeletAccountModal=function(){document.querySelector('.delete-account-modal').style.display='block';document.querySelector('.dark-nilon').style.display='block';};var closeDeletAccountModal=function(){document.querySelector('.delete-account-modal').style.display='none';document.querySelector('.dark-nilon').style.display='none';};var hashPasswordsDelete=function(currentpassword,currentpassword_md5){var junk_output;md5hash(currentpassword,currentpassword_md5,junk_output,0);};return{handleEvent,openDeletAccountModal,closeDeletAccountModal,hashPasswordsDelete};}());document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){profileModule.handleEvent();});
```

Any way to find out what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Hey there! It's possible that the method has been renamed, are you sure it was Delet and not Delete?

Comment: @SecurityObscurity it actually goes as "Delet" and apparently I looked at the wrong error, just edited the post with what actually shows up, sorry.